# Context menu not working on CSS table

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a table on my webpage. I recently changed this from a HTML table to a CSS one. I have a context menu that displays on each row of my table. The context menu was working on the HTML table but not the CSS one.

**HTML:** (*sample of CSS table*)

```
<div class="tbody">
    <div class="td"><%= products[i].productOwner %></div>
    <div class="td"><%= products[i].engineeringOwner %></div>
    <div class="td"><%= products[i].engineeringLead %></div>   
    ...
```

*#contextMenu:*

```
<ul id="contextMenu">
    <li><a href="edit" onclick="location.href=this.href+'?id=' + recordID; return false;">Edit</a></li>
    <li><a onclick="Confirm.render('Delete', 'Are you sure you want to delete this record?', recordID);">Delete</a></li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).bind('contextmenu', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    recordID = $(e.target).parent().attr('id');
    if ($(e.target).hasClass('td')) {
        $('#contextMenu').css({
            left: e.pageX + 'px',
            top: e.pageY + 'px'
        }).show().fadeIn(500, startFocusOut());
    }
    return false;
});
```

I have debugged and confirmed that `$(e.target)` does have `td` class so the `if` statement should be entered